# Find all $a,b,c$ such that $f(x,y,z)=x^2 + 2axy+by^2+cz^2$ is convex, strictly convex and strongly convex

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I need a small hint with convex functions.

Find all $a,b,c$ such that $f(x,y,z)=x^2 + 2axy+by^2+cz^2$ is convex, strictly convex and strongly convex.

To answer if a function is convex and strictly convex it is enough to find all $a,b,c$ such that it's Hessian matrix is positive-defined, e.g $\nabla^2f \succ 0$ ($\nabla^2f \succeq 0 $).

So,

$$
\nabla^2f=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2a & 0 \\
2a & 2b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2c
\end{bmatrix}
\succ 0
$$

According to Sylvester's criterion, we get

$$
\begin{cases}
b-a^2 > 0 \\
c(b-a^2) > 0
\end{cases}
$$

Which means that

$$
\begin{cases}
-\sqrt{b} < a < \sqrt{b} \\
b > 0 \\
c > 0
\end{cases}
$$

My questions are 1) Is the solution I came up with correct? 2) How to find values of $a,b,c$ which guarantee function $f(x,y,z)$ to be strongly convex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have looks right to me.

Comment: Thanks, @subrosar. Any thoughts about strong convexity of $f(x,y,z)$?